# ASP.NET publish trying to copy a non-existant file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, publish, pdb-files

I'm trying to publish an ASP.NET project in VS2010, and am getting the following error:

> Copying file bin\CKFinder.pdb to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\CKFinder.pdb failed. Could not find file 'bin\CKFinder.pdb'.

I had tried using a trial version of CKFinder (with CKEditor), but I backed it out.  I removed all references to CKFinder, including the folders and the references - or so I thought.

Why is this error coming up?  Ideas?

Comment: Update: I went into Project --> Package/Publish Settings, and clicked "Exclude generated debug symbols."  The project is now publishing as I write this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Copying file bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml to ..\bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388119/errorcopying-file-bin-entityframework-sqlserver-xml-to-bin-entityframework-s)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update: I went into Project --> Package/Publish Settings, and clicked "Exclude generated debug symbols."  The project began publishing with no issue.

Update #2 (this is probably the better answer): I tried to publish as debug instead of release (yes, I wanted to keep the debug features in this particular release), and the error came up again.  It turned out that I did not exclude the CKfinder.dll from the project.  Once I did so, it ran with no problem.

Comment: not me...  Error 1 Copying file Views\Default1\Index.cshtml to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Default1\Index.cshtml failed. Could not find file 'Views\Default1\Index.cshtml'.  In VS2012 Express !

Comment: Dah !  The files aren't in the folder but just in the .proj.  SubVersion Commit fail !

Comment: Francois Breton comment proved helpful for me. I had removed a reference to a dll, but TFS did not reflect the same. I had to go and edit my Project.csproj file and remove the <Content Include=OffendingDLL.dll> reference. Save it on disk , VS asked to reload project. Now publishing okay

Comment: @FrançoisBreton thanks man,your comment helped me after wasting 30 mins on web .

Answer (score 47):

I also bumped to this problem. I was receiving the following error, when trying to publish MVCForum 1.7:

> Copying file App_Data\NuGetBackup\Hello.txt to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\App_Data\NuGetBackup\Hello.txt failed. Could not find file 'App_Data\NuGetBackup\Hello.txt'.

[François Breton's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705550/asp-net-publish-trying-to-copy-a-non-existant-file#comment20823846_10721796) helped me achieve the solution.

It's simple:

Open your `.csproj` file with a text editor (Notepad, Notepad++) Visual Studio will open it as a project.

Press `Ctrl` + `F` and search for the file of the problem. In my case the file was "Hello.txt" *without commas*.

Under the `<ItemGroup>` it resided:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="App_Data\NuGetBackup\Hello.txt" />
<Content Include="Content\admin\Admin.css">
    <DependentUpon>Admin.scss</DependentUpon>
</Content>
...More code omitted due to brevity.
```

I deleted the `<Content Include="App_Data\NuGetBackup\Hello.txt" />` line, and voila! Visual Studio allowed me to Preview before publishing!

It will end like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="Content\admin\Admin.css">
    <DependentUpon>Admin.scss</DependentUpon>
</Content>
...More code omitted due to brevity.
```

Comment: This saved my day. I had the same problem but with npm-files. (For example npm-debug.log)

Answer (score 13):

Me just removed **yellow marked** file from my **visual studio solution** & it worked greatly for me because files were **added** and **removed** many times from folders but its not removed from **VS solution project**.

Answer (score 10):

Delete file showing exclamation mark in the solution explorer. It worked for me

[image: Solution explorer with file]

Answer (score 6):

I ran into same problem, i just clicked show all files, and deleted the files that had exclamation mark with them. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your project => unload project => right click again on your newly unloaded project => edit 'myProject.csproj' => Search for the offending files (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) and remove.

If the error appears again within the same parent directory, but now under a different file name, it could be that a user has mistakenly included a file in the project (like I did). All files under the offending directory can be removed. This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You must exclude **bin folder** from project, then republish your project. the way can solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got a similar error but with `.cshtml` files like this:

> copying to Views\Home\About.cshtml to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Home\About.cshtml failed. Could
>   not find file 'Views\Home\About.cshtml'

Looking at the Solution Explorer tree everything seemed fine with no yellow markings but when clicking on a file it gave an error.

> The item 'About.cshtml' does not exist in the project directory. It may have been
>   moved, renamed or deleted.

[image]

Removing the files from Solution solved it for me.

Comment: I remove my .chtml file in my project 
so not Exist File In solution...
 .But on Publish Time Show this error meseage :>>
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Account\Login.cshtml to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Account\Login.cshtml failed. Could not find file 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Views\Account\Login.cshtml'.

Answer (score 1):

I mistakenly included obj Folder to Visual Studio Project. Excluding Obj folder from project fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

Check for bin folder is added in vs explorer. If it was there then exclude from project and check. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had files inside of my directory I intended to publish to.  Deleting these allowed for a successful publish.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to delete publish profile, this error happened to me after I deleted 1 of the EF DbContext. The solution keep track of that file inside publish folder, I recreated the profile and publish successfully.

My error was this

> No DbContext named 'xxxx' was found.

Answer (score 0):

These problems occur when the bin file is included in the project, note that if the bin folder exists in your solution, exclude it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).