# Error Copying file bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml to ..\bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I try to publish my ASP.NET MVC 4 project, I have this error:

> Error 1   Copying file bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml failed. Could not find file 'bin\EntityFramework.SqlServer.xml'.       0   0   Karinoks

there is no error on debugging or run time. It is just showed when I publishing.

Comment: Right click the folder and remove read only permission!

Comment: I found it. some folders was be inactive in project. I sad include to project. and it is solved.

Comment: I will like to raise a issue...i have deleted the file and then rebuild it...it started showing me error `classLib filr is missing` ... then i was having backup of my previous version i took the bin folder from the latest backup and added it to the project...now it worked...can you explain me what is happening here and what had happened...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Delete the `bin` folder from your project directory and rebuild the project.

Then run the project.

Comment: I will like to raise a issue...i have deleted the file and then rebuild it...it started showing me error `classLib file is missing` ... then i was having backup of my previous version i took the bin folder from the latest backup and added it to the project...now it worked...can you explain me what is happening here and what had happened?

Comment: Just to clarify: when I was trying these solutions I deleted the bin/ folder from the disk using the File Explorer. That did not work for me. I had to delete the bin/ folder from the project structure in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 13):

Just **Exclude the bin** folder from the project.

Comment: I will like to raise a issue...i have deleted the file and then rebuild it...it started showing me error classLib filr is missing ... then i was having backup of my previous version i took the bin folder from the latest backup and added it to the project...now it worked...can you explain me what is happening here and what had happened.

Comment: Just to clarify: when I was trying these solutions I deleted the bin/ folder from the disk using the File Explorer. That did not work for me. I had to delete the bin/ folder from the project structure in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6):

Erasing the bin folder solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Erasing the bin folder might not solve the issue all the time because all the `.ddl` are included into to the bin folder so it's better to exclude the obj folder from the project then build it again.

Comment: This just repeats the answer from Muhammad Awais 2.5 years prior.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on you Project
2. Click Publish
3. Go to Settings Tab
4. Click File Publish Options
5. Check All the options in the tab (As seen in attached image)

[image: Example image]